# SQL server, Order by datetime value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to sum the value by date, here is the query i currently have,

```
SELECT     SUM(LineTotalValue) AS Value, DateTimeCreated
FROM         SOPOrderReturnLine AS SOPOrderReturnLine 
WHERE     (AnalysisCode1 LIKE 'value%')
GROUP BY DateTimeCreated
ORDER BY DateTimeCreated desc
```

Here is the what what data looks like from the results of the query.

```
 Value       DateTimeCreated

433.00  2015-01-26 15:36:28.723
135.00  2015-01-26 15:36:13.883
600.00  2015-01-26 15:28:14.957
0.00    2015-01-26 14:45:57.920
58.25   2015-01-26 14:45:21.080
39.08   2015-01-26 14:45:13.443
41.56   2015-01-26 14:45:07.010
99.80   2015-01-26 14:44:56.243
99.99   2015-01-26 14:44:48.590
75.00   2015-01-26 14:44:39.647
```

As you can see as the DateTimeCreated value has the times in it it wont count the value correctly what i want it to do is count based on the date, how to achieve this? changing the data or table design is not an option

Comment: Cast your datetime to a date and group by / order by that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT     SUM(LineTotalValue) AS Value, 
           CONVERT(date, DateTimeCreated)
FROM       SOPOrderReturnLine AS SOPOrderReturnLine 
WHERE      AnalysisCode1 LIKE 'value%'
GROUP BY   CONVERT(date, DateTimeCreated)
ORDER BY   CONVERT(date, DateTimeCreated) desc
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
SELECT     SUM(LineTotalValue) AS Value, 
           CAST(DateTimeCreated AS DATE)
FROM       SOPOrderReturnLine AS SOPOrderReturnLine 
WHERE      AnalysisCode1 LIKE 'value%'
GROUP BY   CAST(DateTimeCreated AS DATE)
ORDER BY   CAST(DateTimeCreated AS DATE) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the values of DateTimeCreated to Date type, just modify the group by:

```
GROUP BY CAST(DateTimeCreated AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

this query will also utilise index if any,

```
SELECT     SUM(LineTotalValue) AS Value, DateTimeCreated
FROM         SOPOrderReturnLine AS SOPOrderReturnLine 
WHERE     (AnalysisCode1 LIKE 'value%')
GROUP BY dateadd(d,0,datediff(day,0,DateTimeCreated))
ORDER BY DateTimeCreated desc
```